# C# child form not refreshing

Tags: c#, winforms, refresh, parent

I have this code that works fine when I call it from within the form, however, when I call the same from the Parent it runs through the code without results:

```
    public void hideHelp()
    {
        //Check in db if panel1 is visible
        SqlCeCommand checkHelp = new SqlCeCommand("Select Show_Help from Options where Opt_Id = 1", this.optionsTableAdapter.Connection);
        if (this.optionsTableAdapter.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed) 
         { this.optionsTableAdapter.Connection.Open(); }

        try
        {
            bool showHelp = (bool)(checkHelp.ExecuteScalar());

            this.panel1.Visible = showHelp;
            this.Refresh();

        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }

    }
```

On Main form I have a toggle button with the following code:

```
    private void tglHelp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (tglHelp.ToggleState.ToString() == "On")
        {
            HRDataSet.OptionsRow updateHelp = hRDataSet.Options.FindByOpt_Id(1);
            try
            {
                updateHelp.Show_Help = true;
                this.optionsTableAdapter.Update(this.hRDataSet);

                Form activeChild = this.ActiveMdiChild;



                if (activeChild.Name == "frmAddEmployees")
                {
                    frmAddEmployees chForm = new frmAddEmployees();
                    chForm.MdiParent = this;


                    chForm.hideHelp();
                }

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName);
            }
            tglHelp.Text = "Help Panel \nOFF";
        }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this piece of code

```
            if (activeChild.Name == "frmAddEmployees") 
            { 
                frmAddEmployees chForm = new frmAddEmployees(); 
                chForm.MdiParent = this; 
                chForm.hideHelp(); 
            }
```

you open another frmAddEmployees and add to the MDI, but you don't show it. 
If your intent was to call the code in the current frmAddEmployees identified by the activeChild you should use something like this

```
            if (activeChild.Name == "frmAddEmployees") 
            { 
                ((frmAddEmployees)activeChild).hideHelp();
            }
```

Comment: Are you sure of the logic in your tglHelp_Click? I can't follow it, but it seems `if (tglHelp.ToggleState.ToString() == "On")` and `updateHelp.Show_Help = true` are setting the help on not off as from `tglHelp.Text = "Help Panel \nOFF";`

Comment: Thanks for your help buddy! It works great and I will take care of the toggle button now :D